# Bicycle Headlights for Commuting. Can't Decide

Tags: commuter, headlights

I'm in the market for my first bicycle headlights, mainly for commuting 10 miles to/from work. The days are getting shorter and I foresee my entire commute will be in the dark in the coming months.

Did some research and I've shortlisted 2 models.

- Ligt & Motion Urban 900
- Knog Blinder 640

Anyone here have first hand experience on either of these 2, or any other models which you highly recommend?

[Best Bike Headlights for Commuting](http://www.thegeekycyclist.com/reviewed-best-bike-headlights-commuting/)

[Best Bike Lights for 2017](https://rideonmagazine.com.au/best-bike-lights-2017/)

Comment: Will you be riding on the road, or on dedicated bike paths, or on unlit trails? What were your criteria to narrow down your choices to the two you mention? There are likely hundreds of models to choose from.

Comment: There are two basic varieties:  1) Headlights that meet legal requirements for making you visible to motorists, plus provide some modest lighting in those situations when you are outside the range of a street light.  2) Headlights that can fully light your path, for some distance ahead, so you can safely navigate dark roads

Comment: https://www.bikelightdatabase.com

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the german brand Busch & Muller, https://www.bumm.de/en/. I bought a headlight from them last year and it has been perfect for my commutes through unlit bike paths.

In Germany there are regulations that states that a bike headlight must not blind oncomming vehicles, so B&M has developed a some very nice lenses/optics for their headlights that prevents that, and at the same time makes the beam very even on the road before you, making them particularly good when you need to not just be seen by others but also light up the road to be able to see it.

The model I have is the Ixon Core that runs on a battery rechargeable by USB. the mounting hardware is solid, the battery life is good, and the build quality is as good as it gets - and rain proof too.

If you live in the USA, I think Peter White Cycles imports and sells them, but if you're in Europe, I guess most german online bike shop will stock them (I got mine from Bike24.com).